# Expected number of draws before a certain sequence appears

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose we're drawing balls marked with numbers with replacement successivelyand uniformly. We want to figure out the expected number of draws we would have to do before we would draw the same(specific) numbered ball consecutively. 
I.e. if the balls are numbered from $1$ to $m$ and if $N$ denotes the number of draws that we do before we had the sequence $(1,1)$ (we draw the ball number $1$ twice sequentially), what is $\mathbb{E}(N)$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried looking at pairs of draws(i.e looking at the first two draws, the draws 2 and 3, 3 and 4, etc.) and determination the probability that a repeat happens in these cases to find the expectation by writing $N$ as a sum of indicator variables, but haven't quite been able to get this to work. In general, I feel like writing $N$ as a sum of indicator variables is a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try letting $E_1$ denote the expected number of more draws needed to get two $1$'s in a row if you just drew a $1$ and $E_2$ denote the expected number of more draws needed to get two $1$'s in a row if you just didn't draw a $1$. Can you get equations in terms of $E_1$ and $E_2$?

Comment: Would this lead to: $E_1 = 1/m + (1-1/m)E_2$ and $E_2 = m + E_1$, which then leads to $E_2 = m^2 + 1$?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I'm not sure how you got those equations. Also, you have to remember a +1.

Comment: Would this then lead to $E_1 = 1 + 1/m + (1-1/m)E_2$ and $E_2 = 1 + (1/m )E_1 + (1-1/m)E_2$?

Comment: The second equation is correct, but why do you have a $+\frac{1}{m}$ in the first one? (I'm assuming its the probability you draw another $1$ and you stop, but that's already accounted for in the $+1$)

Comment: Ah yes indeed, thank you very much!